# Некликабельна//не кликабельна?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Как писать: (**не)кликабельна**

Я понимаю, что это краткое прилагательное с "НЕ". Но все равно не могу понять "как".

- Без "НЕ" употребляется – кликабельна(?).
- Синоним найти не могу.
- Допустим, в предложении нет противопоставления с союзом "а".
- Если нет слов "далеко не, "вовсе не" и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не с краткими прилагательными пишется как с полными: дорога нелегка (трудна, тяжела) = дорога нелёгкая (трудная, тяжёлая).

*Эта ссылка (кнопка) некликабельна(я).*

См. у Розенталя [§ 57. Частица не с прилагательными](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77)

Примечание о синонимах:

> Подобрать синоним удается не всегда, но утвердительный оттенок
>   значения, содержащийся в прилагательном, служит основанием для
>   слитного написания: *Кто-то **нездешний** в часовне на камне сидит
>   (Ж.); У Гервига была какая-то **немужская** изнеженность (Герц.); Юные
>   шалости его… определялись **недетской** вдумчивостью (Леон.); Это один
>   из тех миллионов «**небелых** граждан» Южно-Африканской Республики,
>   которые гневно осудили рабство.*

В том же параграфе - о синтаксической функции.

И ещё одно важное примечание:

> В некоторых случаях возможно двоякое толкование текста и, как
>   следствие, двоякое написание:
>
> *эта задача нетрудная* (утверждается «легкость»);
>
> *эта задача не трудная* (отрицается «трудность»);
>
> *перед нами необычное явление* (т. е. редкое);
>
> *перед нами не обычное явление* (мыслится противопоставление: явление не обычное, а исключительное).

То есть

*эта кнопка некликабельна* (утверждается невозможность клика) и

*эта кнопка не кликабельна* (отрицается возможность клика),

на усмотрение пишущего, что он там имеет в виду.

Comment: А корректны ли Вы в принципе эти словечки:  кликабельный, некликабельный?

Comment: Исчо как! В Викисловаре есть.